# JSRender Template Custom Tag usage

Tags: javascript, jsrender

I want write the JSRender template for rendering the large amount of data .I have refered the following link to know about the JS Render.

http://www.jsviews.com/#tags

From the above link , i understand that we can use the custom Tags and also helpers method in js render template

Which is the best one for good performance?.

Answer (score 0):

In most scenarios it won't make a detectable difference. Your code will be probably almost the same in both cases. You can choose syntactic convenience... If you are really concerned, try both, and measure. Again, depends on what you are optimizing - memory, loading speed...